# Tamanho da Árvore Binária

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão, árvore-binária

Preciso desenvolver um método para calcular o tamanho de uma Árvore Binária porem estou recebendo erro do compilador.

**Código:**

```
class No:
def __init__(self, dado):
    self.esq = None
    self.dir = None
    self.dado = dado 

class Arvore:
def __init__(self):
    self.raiz = None
def pegarRaiz(self):
    return self.raiz

def inserir(self, val):
    if self.raiz == None:
        self.raiz = No(val)
    else:
        self._inserir(val, self.raiz)

def _inserir(self, val, node):
    if val < node.dado:
        if(node.esq != None):
            self._inserir(val, node.esq)
            node.esq.pai = node
        else:
            node.esq = No(val)
    else:
        if node.dir != None:
            self._inserir(val, node.dir)
            node.dir.pai = node
        else:
            node.dir = No(val)

def Altura(self):
    if self.raiz != None:
        self._Altura(self.raiz)
def _Altura(self,test):
    cont = 0
    if test.dir != None or test.esq != None:
        cont += 1
        self._Altura(test.esq)
        self._Altura(test.dir)
    return cont

T = Arvore()
T.inserir(15)
T.inserir(9)
T.inserir(5)
T.inserir(12)
T.inserir(20)
T.Altura()
```

Logo após rodar o código o compilador volta para receber comandos, não mostra para o usuário a altura da árvore.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Já tentou fazer `print(T.Altura())`?

Comment: O compiler retorna "None"

Comment: Ah, sim, pois no método `Altura` você não definiu nenhum retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés disso:

```
        self._Altura(self.raiz)
```

Use isso:

```
        return self._Altura(self.raiz)
```

Ou seja, faltou a palavra `return`.

E também aqui:

```
        cont = 0
```

Use isso:

```
        cont = 1
```

Obviamente, ainda há alguns casos onde a identação está errada.

Comment: Colocando este return recebo uma altura errada para a Árvore.

Comment: @MrPamonha Use `cont = 1`.